# jQuery appending HTML elements out of order

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'll start this off by saying I use JS very infrequently, so this is likely a simple mistake. I came across the need to generate a form on the spot when a button is pressed. After some searching, I decided on using the `append` function from jQuery. Here is the code I wrote:

```
function replyToComment(commentId) {
    var element = document.getElementById("reply-form");
    if (element != null) {
        element.remove()
    }

    const html = `
    <div id="reply-form">
        <label for="comment-form">Comment:</label>
        <form method="post" id="comment-form" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="${csrf_token}"
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <textarea type="text" name="body" maxlength="1500" class="textarea form-control" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="comment-send" style="display:none;" readonly>
            <input type="text" name="comment_id" value=${commentId} style="display:none;" readonly>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>`
    $(`#${commentId}`).append(html)
}
```

When inspecting the final result, the argument passed into the `append` function is out of order:
[image]

I am not sure if the image will load in properly, but if it doesnt, its mostly irrelevant. Am I misusing the `append` function? Is there another way to do this that will handle the data I want to pass in properly?

Comment: Fix your typo's... You never close your `<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="${csrf_token}"` in form... So i guess Browsers redder it wrong so you get butch result.

Comment: If the attributes refers to what I passed into the function as `html`, then i think it is important. The button does not seem to be attached to the form, so I can’t submit it. I believe the button has to be within the form. Perhaps jQuery cannot handle that big of an input for the `apend` function?

Comment: @ikiK I’ll test that out in the morning. You’re probably right. I’ll update the post if you are.

Comment: Also see `insertAdjacentHTML` in JS so you don't have to use jquery just for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you're neglecting to close one of your `input` tags.

You have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="${csrf_token}"
```

This should be:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="${csrf_token}" />
```